# Windows System process utilizes port 8885

Tags: windows, process, port

The port 8885 is used on my windows 7 Pro x64 by the 'System' process (PID:4) and it conflicts with one of my application that uses this port.

I investigated but so far I have no results nor explanations. I tried:

- Local antivirus complete scan
- antivirus uninstall
- 2 online antivirus complete scans
- Use 'tcpview' to close the connection (recreated)
- 'process explorer' (but as it is 'System' process, nothing can be done)
- 'process monitor' (no results)
- registry search
- Google deep searches
- Stackoverflow search

I am stuck - any ideas?

This started to happen after Office 2010 to 2013 upgrade & windows updates but uninstalling 2013 gave also nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "Dell System Detect".